# Insert a progress bar in a MediaWiki page

Tags: php, html, mediawiki

I created a wiki for our team for documentation and to keep track of our project and tasks.

Someone else on the team created a Kanban board. I would like to put a progress bar new to each task to show how much is completed.

I've tried to find an extension to do what I want, there is a bug in the parser so I'm not able to use the TODO extension for media wiki.

I'm posting the question here to see if anyone would have suggestions to accomplish what I want in MediaWiki?

Answer (score 1):

Try [exporting](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Export) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Progress_bar - maybe it would be enough for you (requires [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions)).

Comment: I'm not really sure how to even use templates. when I put the {{Progress bar|<50>}} on the page I get template:progress bar and then tells me to create the page.

Comment: @user770022 The template page probably isn't included in MediaWiki. You'll have to create `Template:Progress bar` with the template's source code.